# Implementing AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, avfoundation

I have tried to implement the `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` in Xamarin.iOS targeting iOS 11 but I have failed to find a working example yet.

Most examples implement the deprecated methods with buffers, but currently the only supported method is:

```
void DidFinishProcessingPhoto(AVCapturePhotoOutput output,
                    AVCapturePhoto photo, Foundation.NSError error);
```

I have found a few updated tutorials for iOS 11, but they usually suggest to use a [`AVCapturePhoto.fileDataRepresentation` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephoto/2873919-filedatarepresentation), but that does not seem to be available in Xamarin for some reason.

Could you please point me in a direction of how to retrieve JPEG and RAW data from `AVCapturePhoto` in Xamarin?

### Update

I have checked the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephoto) for `AVCapturePhoto` and it seems the [Xamarin.iOS class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/AVFoundation.AVCapturePhoto/) is missing many other members like `bracketSettings`, but only the `imageRepresentation` related methods are actually not available in code.

I would be very grateful for an explanation of the reason for this, because without the data representation methods there doesn't seem to be any convenient way to retrieve a `UIImage` from `AVCapturePhoto` apart from using the deprecated delegate methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an open bug/issue scheduled for the Xcode 9.3 support/milestone:

- [Missing bindings in AVCapturePhoto](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/3324)

re: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/4da8016db4330bde0a09b4a5453a26427ca6685d/tests/xtro-sharpie/iOS-AVFoundation.ignore

```
!missing-selector! +AVCapturePhotoBracketSettings::photoBracketSettingsWithRawPixelFormatType:rawFileType:processedFormat:processedFileType:bracketedSettings: not bound
!missing-selector! AVCapturePhoto::fileDataRepresentationWithReplacementMetadata:replacementEmbeddedThumbnailPhotoFormat:replacementEmbeddedThumbnailPixelBuffer:replacementDepthData: not bound
!missing-selector! AVCapturePhotoOutput::availableLivePhotoVideoCodecTypes not bound
!missing-selector! AVCapturePhotoOutput::isCameraCalibrationDataDeliverySupported not bound
!missing-selector! AVCapturePhotoOutput::isDualCameraDualPhotoDeliveryEnabled not bound
!missing-selector! AVCapturePhotoOutput::isDualCameraDualPhotoDeliverySupported not bound
!missing-selector! AVCapturePhotoOutput::setDualCameraDualPhotoDeliveryEnabled: not bound
!missing-selector! AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings::embeddedThumbnailDimensions not bound
!missing-selector! AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings::expectedPhotoCount not bound
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Even after an hour of searching I didn't stumble upon this :-)

Comment: @MartinZikmund I had to implemented them myself for a client so I knew that they were missing :-(