# How do I port a Swift class along with it's extensions to C# for Xamarin iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, .net, swift, xamarin

I'm trying to port AVFoundation code I wrote in Swift, to Xamarin iOS C# classes. I'm not great with Swift but the issue I have with it is pseudo multiple-inheritance pattern that I see with extensions.

Here's a class stub

```swift
class CaptureProcessor : NSObject {
    let captureQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.AVFoundationCamera.CaptureProcessor.queue" 
                       , qos: .utility)
    let callbackParent : ImplementsCallback

    init {}
}
```

and it's extension

```
extension CaptureProcessor : AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, willBeginCaptureFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings) {
        self.callbackParent.willBeginCaptureForCallback(output: output, resolvedSettings: resolvedSettings)
    }
}
```

How would I write these in C# for Xamarin iOS or MAUI, and reliably inherit the delegate call behaviour?

This works, but what's the pattern to inherit the delegate extension?

```
public class CaptureProcessor : NSObject { ... }
```

Comment: this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842931/implementing-avcapturephotocapturedelegate-in-xamarin-ios) might help you.

Comment: Not specifically what I want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to copy this exact structure? Because a Swift extension is just a strategy to extend the definition of a class outside its initial definition.

For simplicity, you could "merge" all implementations of the extension in the original class definition. Using your example:

```swift
class CaptureProcessor : NSObject {
    let captureQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.AVFoundationCamera.CaptureProcessor.queue" 
                       , qos: .utility)
    let callbackParent : ImplementsCallback

    init {}

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, willBeginCaptureFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings) {
        self.callbackParent.willBeginCaptureForCallback(output: output, resolvedSettings: resolvedSettings)
    }
}
```

That is translated this into C# as:

```csharp
using System;
using AVFoundation;
using CoreFoundation;

internal partial class CaptureProcessor : AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate
{
    internal DispatchQueue captureQueue = new DispatchQueue("com.AVFoundationCamera.CaptureProcessor.queue");
    internal IImplementsCallback callbackParent;

    internal CaptureProcessor() : base() { }
    internal CaptureProcessor(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) {}

    public override void DidCapturePhoto(AVCapturePhotoOutput captureOutput, AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings resolvedSettings)
    {
        callbackParent.WillBeginCaptureForCallback(captureOutput, resolvedSettings);
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to keep the definition separation, as the original Swift code, you could try to use C#'s [Partial Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods):

```csharp
using System;
using AVFoundation;
using CoreFoundation;

internal partial class CaptureProcessor : AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate
{
    internal DispatchQueue captureQueue = new DispatchQueue("com.AVFoundationCamera.CaptureProcessor.queue");
    internal IImplementsCallback callbackParent;

    internal CaptureProcessor() : base() { }
    internal CaptureProcessor(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) {}
}

internal partial class CaptureProcessor
{
    public override void DidCapturePhoto(AVCapturePhotoOutput captureOutput, AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings resolvedSettings)
    {
        callbackParent.WillBeginCaptureForCallback(captureOutput, resolvedSettings);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Given that `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` is a class on Xamarin.iOS and not an interface, all partial class definition needs to be a child of AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate.

**=== Edit to include comments explanations ===**

Multiple inheritances will depend on how Xamarin.iOS translates the UIKit/Foundation class into C#. If 2 elements are classes in Xamarin (like NSObject and AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate), you will have to go with the "lower" level as the base class. If you have multiple protocols/interfaces, it is just a "regular" C# interface conformance.

The "issue" with AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate here is how Xamarin.iOS translates Objective-C protocols. Many protocols in UIKit have to be applied to NSObject. While they are constrained protocols in Objective-C/Swift, C# does not have the same constraint rules, so they are translated to Xamarin as Classes, preventing multiple conformance.

When looking at Apple's documentation, any object that extends NSObjectProtocol will be translated to Xamarin.iOS as a class, child of NSObject. Using the same AVKit class as an example:

```swift
public protocol AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate : NSObjectProtocol
```

So it is translated to Xamarin.iOS as:

```csharp
public class AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate : NSObject
```

The trick here would be to, first, check if the Swift class is constrained to `NSObjectProtocol`. For these cases, you can be sure that you can only inherit the lower as the base class since Xamarin.iOS will convert those as a class, even if they are protocols (interfaces) on the native world.

For other cases, check if the protocol was translated into Xamarin's interfaces. If the interface is kept you can use Partial classes to have the same implementation structure as in Swift.

Comment: Main problem is how do I retain NSObject inheritance as well? might not be needed for this specific instance but in general I want to know how multiple inhgeritence like this is translated to Xamarin classes.

Will check it out, thanks! I didn't check if AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate inherits NSObject.

Comment: @JayKannan Multiple inheritances will depend on how Xamarin.iOS translates the UIKit/Foundation class into C#. If 2 elements are classes in Xamarin (like NSObject and AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate), you will have to go with the "lower" level as the base class. If you have multiple protocols/interface, it is just a "regular" C# interface conformance.

Comment: The "issue" with AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate here is how Xamarin.iOS translates Objective-C protocols. Many protocols in UIKit have to be applied to NSObject. While they are constrained protocols in Objective-C/Swift, C# does not have the same constraint rules, so they are translated to Xamarin as Classes, preventing the multiple conformance.

Comment: When looking at Apple's documentation, any object that extends `NSObjectProtocol` will be translated to Xamarin.iOS as a class, child of NSObject. Using the same AVKit class as an example:

`public protocol AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate : NSObjectProtocol`

So it is translated to Xamarin.iOS as:

`public class AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate : NSObject`

Comment: The trick here would be to, first, check if the Swift class is constrained to `NSObjectProtocol`. For these cases, you can be sure that you can only inherit the lower as the base class since Xamarin.iOS will convert those as a class, even if they are protocols (interfaces) on the native world. For other cases, check if the protocol was translated into Xamarin's interfaces. If the interface is kept you can use Partial classes to have the same implementation structure as in Swift.

Comment: Partial classes will still not let you multiple-inherit across different classes. yes Xamarin turns protocols and delegates into full classes. I was wondering how Xamarin handles delegates as a composite instead. I didn't get around to this piece of code yet, so will update when I find the answers.